# Find heap depth faster than O(n^2)

Tags: java, algorithm, heap

Help me optimize the algorithm. 
I have a heap in the array.
Each number in the array indicates a parent. Root is -1.
I need to find the depth of heap.
Example:

Array is 
4 -1 4 1 1

[image: heap_structure]

The answer is 3.

It's my code

```
static int findMax(int[] mas) {
    int a[] = new int[mas.length];
    a[pos] = 1;
    int max = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == 0 && a[mas[i]] != 0) {
                a[i] = a[mas[i]] + 1;
                if (a[i] > max)
                    max = a[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Where pos - position of root.

I also solved this problem with recursion. But tests give me "Time limit exceeded" also.

```
static class Node {
        static int nodesCount = 0;

        int val;
        int deep;
        List<Node> childrens = new ArrayList<>();
        static Set<Integer> deeps = new HashSet<>();

        public Node(int val, int deep) {
            this.val = val;
            this.deep = deep;
            deeps.add(deep);
            nodesCount++;
        }

        public List<Node> getChildrens() {
            return childrens;
        }

        public int getDeep() {
            return deep;
        }
    }
static int findMax(int [] mas){
    Node head = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if (mas[i] == -1)
            head = new Node(i, 1);
    }
    fillChildren(head, mas);
    return Node.deeps.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
}

private static void fillChildren(Node head, int[] mas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if (mas[i] == head.val) {
            Node child = new Node(i, head.getDeep() + 1);
            head.getChildrens().add(child);
            fillChildren(child, mas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Translate your array to `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` as `{parent: [children], ...}`, find root node and do DFS? Should be O(n), or not?

Comment: Yes. I think O(n *lgn). O(n) is unreachable(in my opinion).

Comment: DFS = depth-first search - in this case, depth-first traversal. Each node is visited exactly once.

Comment: `number in the array indicates a parent` - by giving the parent's *key*? *index*?

Comment: This unclear to me. The heap you have is a min heap or a max heap? The heap you show in the diagram, does it have array indexes of the array  `4 -1 4 1 1`?

Comment: I believe using recursion you can achieve O(n)

Comment: Technical note: the presented example does not represent a heap. It is neither a min-heap (parent <= child) nor max-heap (parent >= child).

Comment: The depth of a binary heap is log2(n), rounded up to the next whole number. So if you have 5 nodes, the depth is log2(5)+1, or 3. You can compute the depth in O(1).

Comment: @JimMischel: the heap was not said to be balanced, nor complete, nor even binary. In the worst case, the depth is O(n).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Fair enough, although the tree shown does not meet the definition of any kind of heap that I'm aware of. What the OP shows is just a binary tree.

Comment: @JimMischel: right, the question concerns a rooted tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To substantiate Matej's answer, here is pseudocode.

- associate a D field to every node,
- initialize all D to -1,
- from every node, follow the parent chain until your reach a node with non-negative D,
- if the root is reached, set its D to 0,
- tracing the chain backward, update the D's increasingly.

A chain traversal stops on the first non-negative node met, and all intermediate nodes become non-negative. So the negative nodes are only visited once and this justifies the O(n) behavior.

Updating all nodes in a chain is crucial, otherwise the same nodes can be visited several times. In the worst case, that could lead to O(n²) operations.

It is worth to note that the algorithm requires a stack to make the backward traversal possible. In the worst case, the stack depth can reach n, adding extra O(n) storage space (or the risk of a stack overflow is no care is taken).

A better option might be to use the D field of the traversed nodes to store the "return index" and form a temporary backward chain.

Comment: Why so much complication? I think my answer is simpler with equal space complexity. Also, why don't you call using the Node structure, as you seem to be advocating here, a "[sledgehammer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927480/find-heap-depth-faster-than-on2#comment96621110_54927779)" solution? That structure does not seem to be needed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful comment. The task is done)

Answer (score 1):

Remember depths of visited nodes in an array. Start traversing from first input element to its root and on backtrack store depths to visited nodes array. On each jump from child to parent check if the depth is already calculated. If yes, you don't have to go that route for second time and can use the pre-calculated value directly. Will be O(n).

Comment: @EdwinBuck: you missed the explanation. O(n) is easily proven from the fact that the depth of the nodes is only assigned once, and path traversal is only performed on the nodes with still unknown depth.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: you needn't travel to the root for every node.

Answer (score 0):

All we need is a map that indicates where the children are, then perform a breadth first search. As we can see in the output below, the complexity is O(n).

```js
function f(A){
  let map = {};
  
  A.map((parentIdx, childIdx) => {
    if (map[parentIdx])
      map[parentIdx].push(childIdx);
    else
      map[parentIdx] = [childIdx];
  });
  
  let maxDepth = 0;
  let queue = [[-1, 0]];
  
  while (queue.length){
    const [node, depth] = queue.shift();

    console.log(
      `node: ${node}, children: [${map[node] || ''}], ` +
      `current depth: ${depth}`);

    maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, depth);
    
    if (map[node])
      for (let child of map[node])
        queue.push([child, depth + 1]);
  }
  
  return maxDepth;
}

var arr = [4, -1, 4, 1, 1];
console.log(f(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

While you can find the max depth in O(n) based on your array of parents, as described by Matej, it may be worthwile to transform that array to a tree structure that's more easily navigable in the direction from parent to child node. You already do this with your `Node` class, but your `fillChildren` method has complexity O(n²) as you have to scan the entire array again and again to find the childrens of the current node.

Instead, you could create a `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`, mapping nodes to their child nodes. This way, you can create the entire tree in a single loop over the array, in O(n).

```
static Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> makeTree(int[] parents) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> tree = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        tree.computeIfAbsent(parents[i], x -> new HashSet<>()).add(i);
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Then, you can easily write a recursive function for getting the maximum depth of the tree:

```
static int depth(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> tree, int node) {
    return tree.containsKey(node) 
            ? 1 + tree.get(node).stream().mapToInt(n -> depth(tree, n)).max().getAsInt()
            : 0;
}
```

The complexity for both steps is O(n) if the array represents a tree, as each node is visited exactly once. If the array could also show a directed graph, you should keep track of nodes already visited before. For your example, use it like this:

```
int[] array = {4, -1, 4, 1, 1};
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> tree = makeTree(array);
System.out.println(depth(tree, -1)); // 3
```

---

As with any recursive algorithm, this may hit the maximum recursion depth if the tree is very, very deep. It can be rewritten in an iterative fashion using a `Stack`, but won't be quite as concise then.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.add(-1);
int[] depth = new int[array.length];
while (! stack.isEmpty()) {
    int node = stack.pop();
    for (Integer child : tree.getOrDefault(node, Collections.emptySet())) {
        depth[child] = node == -1 ? 1 : depth[node] + 1;
        stack.add(child);
    }
}
System.out.println(IntStream.of(depth).max().getAsInt());
```

Comment: Nice solution, but doesn't work with extra big arrays. I got exception Failed test #7. Runtime error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapSink(AbstractPipeline.java:517)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
 at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.reduce(IntPipeline.java:461)
 at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.max(IntPipeline.java:424)

Comment: The size of the array is not a problem, but the depth of the tree might be. If the depth is more than the maximum recursion limit, then you can rewrite this with a stack. Did this really justify a downvote?

Comment: This is an inefficient, sledgehammer solution, requiring too much extra space. I guess that "following any of it's branches" should be "following *all* of it's branches".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Seriously, what exactly is the problem? What is it that makes this answer "inefficient", "sledgehammer", or "a monster"? This is just getting silly.